# Doesn't wait Timer for user to click on answers in Android Quiz Game, and quickly run

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have navigation drawer with menu nav items. Now I define for one item, for when clicking on it, open a new activity.Inside this activity, I design layout for start flag game quiz.When clicking on play game Button, the game started so fast without waiting for click user, and finish. Inside "PlayGame" layout, I define one imageView for flags and 4 buttons for answers. Flags name and answers come from the External database. When I debug the app, countDownTimer realise null amount, Everything is correct, Just Timer doesn't wait for use, and playing Quiz is so quickly.

this is my database.

**WorldCountryDatabase**

```
public class WorldCountryDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "databaseHelper";
private static final String DB_NAME = "worldCountries.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "country";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public WorldCountryDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

    File file = new File(DB_PATH + "worldCountries.db");
    if (file.exists())

        openDataBase();

    this.mContext = context;


}

public void createDatabase() {

    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

    if (dbExist) {

        Log.d("MIN1", "Database already Exist");

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    try {
        copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("MIN2", e.getMessage());

    }


}

private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {


        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("MIN3", e.getMessage());

    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
        SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
    }
    super.close();

}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    try {


        InputStream in = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }


        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

        Log.d("MIN4", "Database copy");


    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("MIN5", e.getMessage());

    }
}

public Cursor QueryData(String query) {
    return database.rawQuery(query, null);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    Log.d("MIN6", "onCreate");



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Upgrading Database from version" + oldVersion + "To" + newVersion +
            "Which will destroy all  oldest data");


    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public void openDataBase() {

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Log.d("MIN7", "Opened database");


}

// CRUD Table
public List<Questions> getAllQuestions() {

    List<Questions> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY Random()", null);
        if (c == null) return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            int Id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            String Image = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
            String AnswerA = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerA"));
            String AnswerB = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerB"));
            String AnswerC = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerC"));
            String AnswerD = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerD"));
            String CorrectAnswer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CorrectAnswer"));

            Questions question = new Questions(Id, Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer);
            questionsList.add(question);


                } while (c.moveToNext());
                c.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    database.close();
    return questionsList;
}



// Insert Score to Ranking table.
public void insertScore(double score) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put("Score", score);
    db.insert("Ranking", null, content);
}

// Get score and sort Ranking.
public List<Ranking> getRanking() {

    List<Ranking> rankingList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;
    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY Score DESC;", null);
        if (c == null) return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {

            int ID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            int Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Score"));

            Ranking ranking = new Ranking(ID, Score);
            rankingList.add(ranking);


        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
    return rankingList;
}



public int getPlayCount(int level)
{
    int result = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c;
    try{
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT PlayCount FROM UserPlayCount WHERE Level="+level+";",null);
        if(c == null) return 0;
        c.moveToNext();
        do{
            result  = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PlayCount"));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public void updatePlayCount(int level,int playCount)
{
    String query = String.format("UPDATE UserPlayCount Set PlayCount = %d WHERE Level = %d",playCount,level);
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

this is my ChoicGame class.

**ChoiceGame**

```
public class ChoiceGame extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView modeText;
SeekBar seekBarMode;
Button playGame, scoreGame;
WorldCountryDatabase worldCountryDatabase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_flag);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    modeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.modeText);
    seekBarMode = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMode);
    playGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playGame);
    scoreGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scoreGame);

    worldCountryDatabase = new WorldCountryDatabase(this);
    try {
        worldCountryDatabase.createDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Event
    seekBarMode.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (progress == 0)
                modeText.setText(Common.MODE.EASY.toString());
            else if (progress == 1)
                modeText.setText(Common.MODE.MEDIUM.toString());
            else if (progress == 2)
                modeText.setText(Common.MODE.HARD.toString());
            else if (progress == 3)
                modeText.setText(Common.MODE.HARDEST.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    playGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayGameCountry.class);
            intent.putExtra("Mode", getPlayMode()); // Send Mode to Playing page
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    scoreGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreGame.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}



private String getPlayMode() {
    if (seekBarMode.getProgress() == 0)
        return Common.MODE.EASY.toString();
    else if (seekBarMode.getProgress() == 1)
        return Common.MODE.MEDIUM.toString();
    else if (seekBarMode.getProgress() == 2)
        return Common.MODE.HARD.toString();
    else
        return Common.MODE.HARDEST.toString();
}
```

}

and at last this is my PlayingGame class.

**PlayingGmae**

```
public class PlayGameCountry extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

final static long INTERVAL = 1; // 1 second
final static long TIMEOUT = 7; // 1 second

CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
int progressValue = 0;

int score = 0, index = 0, thisQuestion = 0, correctAnswer, totalQuestions;
List<Questions> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
String mode;

ProgressBar progressBar;
ImageView flagCountry;
TextView scoreText, numberQuestion;
Button answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD;

WorldCountryDatabase worldCountryDatabase;
ChoiceGame choiceGame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game_country);

    // Get data from ChoiceGame
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)

        mode = bundle.getString("Mode");


    worldCountryDatabase = new WorldCountryDatabase(this);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    flagCountry = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagQuiz);
    scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
    numberQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trueAnswer);

    answerA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstAnswer);
    answerB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secondAnswer);
    answerC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thirthAnswer);
    answerD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forthAnswer);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressUser);

    answerA.setOnClickListener(this);
    answerB.setOnClickListener(this);
    answerC.setOnClickListener(this);
    answerD.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    questionsList = this.getQuestionMode(mode);
    assert questionsList != null;
    totalQuestions = questionsList.size();

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(INTERVAL, TIMEOUT) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
            progressValue++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            showQuestion(++index);

        }
    };
    showQuestion(index);
}

private void showQuestion(int index) {

    if (index < totalQuestions) {
        thisQuestion++;
        numberQuestion.setText(String.format("%d/%d", thisQuestion, totalQuestions));
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressValue = 0;

        int ImageId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(questionsList.get(index).getImage().toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());
        flagCountry.setBackgroundResource(ImageId);
        answerA.setText(questionsList.get(index).getAnswerA());
        answerB.setText(questionsList.get(index).getAnswerB());
        answerC.setText(questionsList.get(index).getAnswerC());
        answerD.setText(questionsList.get(index).getAnswerD());


        countDownTimer.start();
    } else {
        Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Done.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("SCORE", score);
        bundle.putInt("TOTAL", totalQuestions);
        bundle.putInt("CORRECT", correctAnswer);
        scoreIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(scoreIntent);
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    countDownTimer.cancel();

    if (index < totalQuestions) {

        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;

        if (clickedButton.getText().equals(questionsList.get(index).getCorrectAnswer()))

        {

            score += 10; // increase score

            correctAnswer++; //increase correct answer

            showQuestion(++index);

        } else

            showQuestion(++index); // If choose right , just go to next question


        scoreText.setText(String.format("%d", score));
    }
}

private List<Questions> getQuestionMode(String mode) {

    List<Questions> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    worldCountryDatabase = new WorldCountryDatabase(this);

    try {
        worldCountryDatabase.createDatabase();
        worldCountryDatabase.openDataBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int limit = 0;
    if (mode.equals(Common.MODE.EASY.toString()))
        limit = 30;
    else if (mode.equals(Common.MODE.MEDIUM.toString()))
        limit = 50;
    else if (mode.equals(Common.MODE.HARD.toString()))
        limit = 100;
    else if (mode.equals(Common.MODE.HARDEST.toString()))
        limit = 200;
    try {

        Cursor cursor = worldCountryDatabase.QueryData(String.format("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY Random() LIMIT %d", limit));

        if (cursor == null) return null;
        if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            do {


                int Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String Image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image"));
                String AnswerA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AnswerA"));
                String AnswerB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AnswerB"));
                String AnswerC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AnswerC"));
                String AnswerD = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("AnswerD"));
                String CorrectAnswer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CorrectAnswer"));

                Questions question = new Questions(Id, Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer);
                questionList.add(question);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            worldCountryDatabase.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return questionList;
}
```

}

At the first, I defining "**getQuestionMode**" method inside WorldCountryDatabase, but the app doesn't go to the **PlayingCountryGame** layout and open ScoreGame class. After I define "getQuestionMode" method inside **PlayingCountryGame** class. I hope to tell clear my problem.

Please help me, good friends. **Thanks** to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you problem is the constructor and values.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long, long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long,%20long))

The constructor need the time on milliseconds and not seconds. Y ou need convert 1 second to 1000 ms.

```
final static long INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 second -> 1000 milliseconds
final static long TIMEOUT = 7000; // 7 seconds -> 7000 milliseconds
```

And the order of the params.

If you want wait 7 second the constructor is:

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TIMEOUT, INTERVAL){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks dear. I don't notice this. Thanks very a lot.:)